# Setup Nginx for File sharing Website

Tags: nginx

My Nginx is very slow after running for 10 mins I use nginx for My file sharing website https://rahim-soft.org but I don't know how to speed up the nginx to server 500 Clients per/sec to download data from my server  I am very basic in this field 
When I start nginx my server hang 
My Server details:
CPU 12 Cores 2.3GHz 4 CPU
RAM 32GB
Uplink 1GB/s
HDD 10TB
Please help me in this thanks anyone in advance

Comment: You need someone who can fine tune your server and not just nginx config. You should probably consult with a professional to do that for you

Comment: Consider using a CDN, [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/) could be a good start